# Will closing vents in closet and bathrooms help cool other areas better?

Tags: hvac

I have a large 4 bedroom ranch home. The two smaller bedrooms never get as cool as rest of home. Master bedroom is cold enough to hang meat. Return and thermostat are in hallway. Can I close vents in bathrooms, closet, laundry area to help cool those two small bedrooms?

Comment: Are these bedroom furthest from the air handler? Are these other rooms near them?

Comment: The two smaller bedrooms are closet to the air handler. I think another problem is that those vents are directly over the door and the air just goes right back out to the return, which is right outside between the the two smaller bedrooms. Considering having ceiling vents installed in these two bedrooms to move vents away from the door.

Comment: That does sound like a problem. Vents should be near the exterior walls (windows) if possible. Anyway, a simple way to test your theory is close the doors and see if that helps keep them cooler.

Comment: I believe the contractor wanted to save money by installing the vents/ducts where he did as it is a development with many of the same style homes. I have tried closing the doors, rooms get even more stuffy/warm. Someday, if I can afford it, I will see about moving vents.

Comment: It appears the ducts for these rooms are routed in the attic so moving should not be hard. The ducts may need to be one size larger, too, but hard to know without the load calculations. Do the other homes with your floorplan have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, all the homes with my floor plan struggle with this. Next time I have tune-up, I will bring up this issue and see if the ducts are too small or needs to be relocated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then duct size or placement is the issue for sure. The question would be whether increasing size would have a noticeable negative impact on any rooms further down the line though it sounds like you could use less in the MB. You could partially close the vent(s) in the MB to help get more to the others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work, but it could be hard on the furnace blower motor if you close too many vents.

I actually do this in my tri-level home - during the summer I close some of the vents on the lower levels so more cool air makes it upstairs, and in the winter I close vents on the upper levels so the lower levels aren't as cold.

Comment: In my opinion, all homes need seasonal tuning, and stress on the furnace is rarely a concern. If you're closing so many vents that pressure increases dramatically, you're doing home ownership wrong. :)